# Unable to create a JSON structure for tree beard reactjs

Tags: javascript, json

How can I create the JSON from the following. 
( I used map function to traverse through the data but unable to build a JSON structure in react. I am familiar to build in C# using LINQ and list but as I am Naive on reactJS not sure how to approach this.)

```
const prodData =
{
    "id": 1,
    "brandName":"Brand A",
    "steps": [
       {
          "stepsID": "stepsID1",
           "businessType": [
             {
                "businessType": 1,
                "businessName": "Product 1",
                "products": [
                   {
                      "productID": 11,
                      "productName": "product 11",
                      "productValue": 1,

                   },
                   {
                      "productID": 12,
                      "productName": "product 12",
                      "productValue": 2,
                   }
                ]
             }
          ],
          {
          "stepsID": "stepsID2",
           "businessType": [
             {
                "businessType": 2,
                "businessName": "Product 2",
                "products": [
                   {
                      "productID": 21,
                      "productName": "product 21",
                      "productValue": 3,

                   },
                   {
                      "productID": 22,
                      "productName": "product 22",
                      "productValue": 4,
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
         }
       }
    }
```

to build the data for react treebeard tree as follows:

```
const sdata = {
    name: 'Brand A',
    toggled: true,
    children: [
    {
        name: 'stepsID1',
          children: [
                {
            "businessName": "Product 1",
            "products": [
               {
                  "productID": 11,
                  "productName": "product 11",
                  "productValue": 1,

               },
               {
                  "productID": 12,
                  "productName": "product 12",
                  "productValue": 2,
               }
            ]
            ]
         }
        ],
        name: 'stepsID2',
          children: [
                {
            "businessName": "Product 2",
            "products": [
               {
                  "productID": 21,
                  "productName": "product 21",
                  "productValue": 3,

               },
               {
                  "productID": 22,
                  "productName": "product 22",
                  "productValue": 4,
               }
            ]
            ]
         }
        ]
     };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "react tree"?

Comment: It is the JSON structured data to build the React  treebeard Tree. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-treebeard

Comment: I suggest breaking this into smaller pieces. Can you write code to create the `sdata` structure without `children`?

Comment: As another note, you're missing a `,` after `"brandName":"Brand A"`

Answer (score 0):

The following code sample will transform your input data into the desired format. As a note; with your background in C# and LINQ you'll likely be familiar with LINQ's `.Select()` method. In javascript, the `.map(fn)` is roughly equivalent to `.Select(fn)`.

```js
/* 
Your input data (corrected from malformed data in your question)
*/
const prodData = {
    'id': 1,
    'brandName': 'Brand A',
    'steps': [{
        'stepsID': 'stepsID1',
        'businessType': [{
            'businessType': 1,
            'businessName': 'Product 1',
            'products': [{
                    'productID': 11,
                    'productName': 'product 11',
                    'productValue': 1,

                },
                {
                    'productID': 12,
                    'productName': 'product 12',
                    'productValue': 2,
                }
            ]
        }],

    }, {
        'stepsID': 'stepsID2',
        'businessType': [{
            'businessType': 2,
            'businessName': 'Product 2',
            'products': [{
                    'productID': 21,
                    'productName': 'product 21',
                    'productValue': 3,

                },
                {
                    'productID': 22,
                    'productName': 'product 22',
                    'productValue': 4,
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}

/*
Helper function checks input data is array, guarantees an array is returned
*/
function asArray(object) {
    return Array.isArray(object) ? object : []
}

/*
Inline mapping of input data, to yield data in desired shape
*/
const sdata = {
    name: prodData.brandName || '',
    toggled: true,
    children: asArray(prodData.steps)
        .map(step => {

            const children = asArray(step.businessType)
                .map(businessType => {

                    const products = asArray(businessType.products)
                        .map(product => {

                            return {
                                productID: product.productID,
                                productName: product.productName,
                                productValue: product.productValue,
                            }
                        })

                    return {
                        businessName: businessType.businessName,
                        products
                    }
                })

            return {
                name: step.stepsID,
                children,
            }
        }),
}

console.log('input', JSON.stringify(prodData, null, ' '))
console.log('output', JSON.stringify(sdata, null, ' '))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I would not know the values this was just an example I was trying to explain. It needs to be dynamic and  wont be sure if the data has children to display. SImilar to building an object in C#.

Comment: True, it is dynamic. I won't be able to know anything until I get the data because it is upto the user to save the info. They may or may not save because the information is editable and the user can comeback anytime to fill the rest of the info. I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It gives {"name":"Brand A","toggled":true,"children":[null,null]}

Comment: Can you please check the question now?

Comment: your input json is malformed - please see updated answer to your revised question. does this work for you?